# Error in 6 lines of code? Cannot identify why code is not giving correct sum(maybe something with the variables?)

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to find the error in this code with two variables but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
num=5 
i=1 
 sum=0
while i<=num: 
    sum+=i
print(sum)
```

Comment: indentation perhaps?

Comment: Since you're not incrementing i this will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to make a good [mcve], please describe exactly what the problem is. Are you getting an error (maybe due to your indentation)? Or is the output you're getting not what you are expecting? (In which case, please provide the current and the expected outputs)

Comment: ` sum=0` must be indended 1 space back.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is always less than `num`. You have an infinite loop. Also, you need to unindent the sum and indent the print if you want to see it increment the loop. See below for a working example.

```
num=5 
i=1 
sum=0

while sum<=num: 
    sum+=i
    print(sum)
```